# HTML5 Canvas stroke() changing color between draws

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I've created a very simple JavaScript snippet to illustrate a weird HTML5 canvas behavior that I have been experiencing.

I keep drawing the same set of strokes, just in a different order, every 100ms. Why is it that the color of some of the strokes keeps changing? It only happens when I shuffle the draw order between calls, even though the lines are drawn in the same location and same color each frame.

```js
const canvasWidth = 500;
const gapBetweenLines = 5;
const nbrLines = canvasWidth / gapBetweenLines;
const canvasHeight = 500;

const canvas = document.getElementById('map');
canvas.width = canvasWidth;
canvas.height = canvasHeight;

// create an array of line objects, each with a with random color
let lines = [];
for (let i = 0; i < nbrLines; i++) {
  lines.push({
    index: i,
    x: i * gapBetweenLines,
    color: '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16)
  });
}

// function to shuffle the given array in place
function shuffle(array) {
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
  }
}

// draw lines on the canvas at specific intervals with the random colors
function drawLines() {
  const shuffledLines = [...lines];
  shuffle(shuffledLines);

  let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  for (let i = 0; i < nbrLines; i++) {
    const line = shuffledLines[i];
    ctx.strokeStyle = line.color;
    // ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(line.x, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(line.x, canvasHeight);
    ctx.stroke();
    // ctx.restore();
  }
}

// call the drawLines function every 100ms
setInterval(drawLines, 100);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Flickering Lines</h1>
    <canvas id="map"></canvas>
    <div id="lineinfo"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The past day had me spending an embarrassing amount of time trying to narrow down the cause of this. Is there something about HTML5 Canvas drawing that I simply misunderstand?

Saving and restoring the context between each stroke does not make any difference.

Comment: You can probably turn this into a runnable snippet in your post, rather than needing jsfiddle, which will let folks click "copy snippet to answer" so they can show the corrected code. Also, reduce the complexity: surely this doesn't require 100 lines to show off, so reduce it until you (ideally) have this happen with a single line, so you can much more easily debug its values.

Comment: (as final hint: change your loop to `for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {...`: you know you're only drawing a single line now, but what do you observe _actually_ happening?)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans. I have switched to a snippet.  Drawing single lines does not exhibit the flicker behavior. I think I've discovered a Canvas version of the double-slit experiment :(

Comment: I created this example in order to send a bug report to the Safari team; the flicker is persistent there no matter what I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your color generation.

> ```js
> color: '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16)
> ```

`Number#toString(16)` does not pad the returned string with zeroes:

```js
console.log(12..toString(16)) // "c", not "0C"
```

This means that in your code, some of your lines may have their `color` property set to values that aren't a valid HEX format (e.g a five or two chars HEX is invalid).

To fix that, you can force your color generator to be always 6 length by padding as many zeroes as needed using the [`String#padStart()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) method.

```js
const canvasWidth = 500;
const gapBetweenLines = 5;
const nbrLines = canvasWidth / gapBetweenLines;
const canvasHeight = 500;

const canvas = document.getElementById('map');
canvas.width = canvasWidth;
canvas.height = canvasHeight;

// create an array of line objects, each with a with random color
let lines = [];
for (let i = 0; i < nbrLines; i++) {
  lines.push({
    index: i,
    x: i * gapBetweenLines,
    color: '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16)
      // force always 6 length
      .padStart(6, "0")
  });
}

// function to shuffle the given array in place
function shuffle(array) {
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
  }
}

// draw lines on the canvas at specific intervals with the random colors
function drawLines() {
  const shuffledLines = [...lines];
  shuffle(shuffledLines);

  let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  for (let i = 0; i < nbrLines; i++) {
    const line = shuffledLines[i];
    ctx.strokeStyle = line.color;
    // ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(line.x, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(line.x, canvasHeight);
    ctx.stroke();
    // ctx.restore();
  }
}

// call the drawLines function every 100ms
setInterval(drawLines, 100);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Flickering Lines</h1>
    <canvas id="map"></canvas>
    <div id="lineinfo"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! That did solve the problem in Chrome and Firefox. However, Safari still flickers, which is the original reason I built this example. I believe it may be a recent bug in Safari...

Comment: Then that's another problem. You may want to edit your yesterday's question specifically about Safari with this snippet. In the mean time I'll investigate on my side.

Comment: Yes, I am going to do exactly that. I appreciate you @Kaiido. Between these two issues, I felt like I was going crazy...

Comment: I feel you, that's part of the charm in chasing browser bugs ;-)